# Что означает такого вида функция?

Tags: javascript

```
 $(function() {
   //какой-то код
 });
```

Comment: В данном виде это лишь обыкновенная функция, обёрнутая в ничего не делающие скобки, подозреваю рядом должен быть ещё какой-то код

Comment: andreymal, например "$"

Comment: А вот это меняет абсолютно всё и обязано быть указано в самом вопросе

Comment: а что может быть вместо "$" ?

Comment: Абсолютно что угодно :)

Comment: ну в данном случае это объект jquery

Comment: Это не замыкание? дайте определение чтобы гуглить :) если знаете

Answer (score 2):

Эта функция обозначает, что код в ней будет выполнятся сразу же после загрузки страницы. Т.е. вы указываете в неё функции и она выполнится сразу после загрузки страницы.

Код запускается, как только DOM готовы взаимодействовать. Иногда лучше использовать `window.onload`, т.к. этот код запускается после того, как страница полностью прогрузится:

```
window.onload = function() {};
```

В случае с Jquery так:

```
$(window).load(function() {});
```

Comment: Функция из вопроса сама выполняться не будет

Comment: А вот теперь, когда вопрос изменили, этот ответ ближе к правде, но неполный

Comment: ну или же:
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(relocate);

 });

Comment: @GoodNew5, нет. Эта функция вызывается при скролле окна

Comment: Она выполняется сразу же после того, как будет загружен весь ДОМ. И всё. Не "зачастую" никаких, а именно так. И предложение "код в ней будет выполнятся сразу же после загрузки страницы" - <b>неправильное</b>, функция не делает этого. Для этого существует `.onload`.

Comment: @VostokSisters, увы, не знаю почему, но бывало, что не прогружалось

Answer (score 2):

Эта функция представляет собой краткую запись для

```
$(document).ready(function(){
...
})`
```

Запускается как только DOM-ом можно манипулировать.

> Источник: [$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)